# Hazelcast transformdata before predicate is applied

Tags: transform, predicate, hazelcast

I have a requirement where I have to apply filter on data where data needs to be rounded off before the filter/data predicate is applied.
For ex all value < than 2 then a value = 1.9 should not be returned

So before I call the entrySet(predicate) I was wondering if I could to transform the data entries to rounded off value ?

Any help and pointers would be great

Answer (score 1):

Probably the EntryProcessor is your friend. You can read and transform data with it very easily.

Comment: If this is working on a very big dataset will not this effect performance ?

Comment: You shouldn't run long running data transformations on using an EntryProcessor but for value extraction or stuff this works nicely. You might also want to look into the aggregations api.